# O que é o parâmetro flush da função print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Percebi que existe o parâmetro `flush` na função `print` do Python:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Sei que:

- O parâmetro `*objects` define a lista de valores a serem exibidos;
- O parâmetro `sep` define o caractere entre os valores;
- O parâmetro `end` o valor que será impresso ao final;
- E o parâmetro `file` define para onde será enviado os valores;

Mas e o parâmetro `flush`? Qual é a função dele?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

O `print` usa `stdout`, como C. Isso nada mais é do que o "arquivo" no sistema operacional pra onde a saída de texto de um programa é mandada, e assim pode ser mostrada pro usuário.

Por padrão, o `stdout` é bufferizado; quer dizer, ele guarda os dados que recebe sem mostrá-los até que receba o código especial de nova linha `\n`.

---

A função `print` do Python por padrão automaticamente bota um caractere de nova linha em qualquer string que você mande pra ela. Mas às vezes, esse comportamento não é desejado e você deseja usar dois `prints` pra mostrar alguma coisa na mesma linha. Nesse caso, você vai usar o argumento `end` da função `print` pra terminar a string com alguma coisa diferente do caractere de nova linha (ou com uma string vazia, pra não printar nada além do que você mandou).

Por exemplo, você pode esperar que o código a seguir printe vários pontos na mesma linha, um a cada 0.5s:

```
import time

for _ in range(5):
    print('.', end='')
    time.sleep(0.5)
print(' Pronto!')
```

Mas o que realmente acontece na maioria dos casos é que nada acontece por 2.5s e depois todos os pontos aparecem de uma vez.

Isso acontece porque o `stdout` por padrão não mostra nada até que ele receba uma linha nova, que não estamos mandando até o final.

---

Então como remediamos esse problema?

Simples, basta usar o `flush` pra forçar que o resultado apareça imediatamente, mesmo sem linha nova:

```
import time

for _ in range(5):
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
print(' Pronto!')
```

Vale mencionar que o `flush` como argumento pro `print` só está disponível a partir do Python 3.3. Antes disso, ele tinha que ser chamado manualmente:

```
import sys
import time

for _ in range(5):
    print('.', end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
print(' Pronto!')
```

Comment: Em PHP qual seria a função equivalente?
Seria algo utilizando ob_start(); e flush();?

Answer (score -3):

Além do que Pedro comentou em sua resposta.

O flush pode ser útil em alguns casos como quando o programa gera uma `exception`, ou onde há muito processamento de forma abrupta no programa, após o print.

Em ambos os caso, é como se o programa não desse tempo para o stdout processar não deixando exibir o `print`, então para garantir que o print ocorra no tempo certo, basta adicionar o `flush=True`

Comment: Comentários devem ser adicionados na área de comentários, não de resposta. Dê uma olhada no [tour] que tem umas dicas legais de como interagir corretamente com a comunidade

Comment: Dependendo da quantidade de pontos da reputação não é possível comentar, então pra novos usuários leva um tempo até conseguir a quantidade de pontos necessário para conseguir comentar nas perguntas

Comment: Exato @Juven_v , eu não tenho reputação para comentar(só posso comentar este pois fui eu que publiquei a resposta)

Comment: @RenatoJunior como eu ainda não tenho reputação para adicionar comentário, eu deveria editar a resposta que já foi feita? Aparentemente, ninguém corrigiu falando que estou errado, apenas deram negativo por ser um comentário feito como resposta. E acho estranho editar a resposta de outro.
Pergunto isso com sinceridade, quero me "evoluir" nos stacks, mas é difícil quando não se tem uma pontuação alta para comentar, e as perguntas que estão ao domínio já estão respondidas.