# Por que o print() imprime as saídas uma abaixo da outra e não ao lado?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Continuando meus estudos em Python, surgiu uma nova dúvida. Antes de perguntar, pesquisei aqui no SOpt utilizando a expressão "print ao lado no Python" e não encontrei nada que pudesse matar minha dúvida e solucionar o problema. Então vamos lá:

Escrevi o seguinte código, bem simples, só para ilustrar o problema, vamos a ele:

```
a = int(input("Digite o primeiro número: "))
b = int(input("Digite o segundo número: "))
for i in range(a+1,b):
    print(i)
```

Obtive a seguinte saída:

```
Digite o primeiro número: 5
Digite o segundo número: 20
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
>>>
```

A dúvida é a seguinte: Por que a função `print()` sempre imprime as saídas dessa forma, uma embaixo da outra? Como fazê-la imprimir as saídas uma ao lado da outra sem usar recursos de listas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A assinatura da função [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) é a seguinte:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

O terceiro parametro, end, é o que o python irá colocar após a sua string (quebra de linha por padrão). Voce pode sobrescrever ele a vontade.

```
a = int(input("Digite o primeiro número: "))
b = int(input("Digite o segundo número: "))
for i in range(a+1,b):
    print(i, end=' ')

Digite o primeiro número: 5
Digite o segundo número: 20
6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
>>>
```

Comment: Sim, testei com uma vírgula e com espaços vazios, funcionou. O que seria o parâmetro `flush`?

Comment: Sobre o flush https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291779/o-que-é-o-flush-do-print-no-python

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer desta forma utilizando o `Python 2`

```
print "Seu texto",
```

E desta forma utilizando o `Python 3`

```
print("Seu texto", end="", flush=True)
```

> A função `print` tem um parâmetro final cujo padrão é "\ n".
>   Configurá-lo uma `string` vazia impede que ele crie uma nova linha no
>   final.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-multiple-prints-on-the-same-line)

Comment: Deu certo, mas aí a saída ficou com todos os números colados um no outro, como se fosse um grande número com vários dígitos. Entretanto, uma alteração no que você postou fez dar certo. Fiz assim: `print(i,end=",",flush=True)`.

Comment: Isso, o end troca o padrão '\n' que é a quebra de linha por "" que é uma string vazia, então ao colocar o "," ele troca o '\n' por virgula ou qualquer outra string que desejar :)

Answer (score 1):

O `print()` é uma função `Buil-in` do `Python` que possui alguns argumentos definidos por padrão, vejamos:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Podemos alternar o argumento `end` caso desejarmos fazer um `print` diferenciado, como por exemplo:

```
print(i, end=' ')
```

Teremos como resultado:

`output: 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19`